# What is a fair way to compare models after model selection procedure?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, cross-validation, predictive-models, model-selection

The question is phrased a bit awkwardly probably, but let me explain it in more detail.

I am using feedforward neural nets with one hidden layer to model a variable of interest. I have a set of inputs with different physical meanings. I want to train several neural nets with different inputs, say *M* different input sets (physical interpretation of different input sets and therefore models is different). I plan to use repeated double cross validation (rdCV) to select an optimal number of neurons in the hidden layer for each set of inputs. Thus, I will end up with *M* models with different inputs (and for each I will have its own number of neurons in the hidden layer).

My question is, will it be fair to compare those models between each other using their averaged performance on the test sets (outer loop of rdCV) afterwards? The reason to obtain several ‘final’ models with different inputs is to assess which influence those inputs have on the variable I’d like to model.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Will each model have just 1 input variable & 1 output variable?

Comment: @gung Thank you for asking. Each model always have 1 output variable, but the number of input variables is different from one model to another (from ~10 to ~100).

Comment: What causes the different number of inputs? Are those different number of inputs a reflection of looking at the same training examples in different ways? Or are there different training sets, each with their own features?

Comment: @dimpol It is more like the second option. Although some models may have some features in common. A specific example for my case: input variables to model #k are the same as input variables to model #(k+1) plus several new features.

Comment: If you are trying to predict the same training and test-cases, just with different features, then you can directly compare them. I would go for 2-levels of cross-validation sets. So 1 set to train all models and all parameters, the first cross-validation set to select the best parameters for each model and the second cross-validation set to compare the results of different models and select the best model. Finally you could have a test-set to have an indication of the final performance of the chosen model+parameters.

Comment: @dimpol Thank you! I think I got it. Just to clarify, by parameters of a model do you mean a number of neurons in the hidden layer (selected in the first CV round)? And then I do compare models (with selected number of neurons in the first CV round) with different inputs in the second CV round and claim the accuracy of the model on the independent test set, right?

Comment: Yes, so if you have 1 labelled-set of examples (with different models using different features of that set, but in the end using the same examples). You could split that set into 4 subsets and train every model with every hyper-parameter setting on the same first subset. Then choose the best parameters of each model using the second subset etc. And indeed: the number of hidden neurons is an example of a (hyper-)parameter I was referring to